# Can not open file when file's name is unicode character

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Explorer.exe", @"/select" + FilePath). Can not open file when file's name is unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283417/c-system-diagnostics-process-startexplorer-exe-select-filepath-can)

I want to open file's location with window Explorer. I am using C# with code

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Explorer.exe", @"/select," + FilePath)

it works well with simple English character, but it could not open the file's location if the file's name is Unicode character (Thia language).

Anyone could help please?

Comment: just discussed today in this other question, not the same but very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283417/c-system-diagnostics-process-startexplorer-exe-select-filepath-can

Comment: Kinda hopeless if he just copies the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, command line arguments get flattened down to the current ANSI code page and back to Unicode in too many contexts. You could *try* manually invoking CreateProcess but there's no guarantee that will work.