SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems Win32 API doesn't work on Go, but works on C#
I am trying to open a Windows Explorer window with specified items in a particular folder selected.
I tried to implement the program using SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems Win32 API with C#. Following the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262552
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

SelectInFileExplorer("C:\\Users");

void SelectInFileExplorer(string fullPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullPath))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fullPath");

    fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fullPath);

    IntPtr pidlList = NativeMethods.ILCreateFromPathW(fullPath);
    if (pidlList != IntPtr.Zero)
        try
        {
            // Open parent folder and select item
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(NativeMethods.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidlList, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0));
        }
        finally
        {
            NativeMethods.ILFree(pidlList);
        }
}

static class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern void ILFree(IntPtr pidlList);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr ILCreateFromPathW(string pszPath);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(IntPtr pidlList, uint cild, IntPtr children, uint dwFlags);
}

It worked, but now I would like to implement the same thing using Go.
Here is my code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    SelectInFileExplorer("C:\\Users")
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}

func SelectInFileExplorer(fullPath string) {
    if fullPath == "" {
        panic("fullPath cannot be empty")
    }

    fullPath, _ = filepath.Abs(fullPath)

    pidlList, err := ILCreateFromPathW(fullPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer ILFree(pidlList)

    // Open parent folder and select item
    err = SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidlList, 0, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func ILFree(pidlList uintptr) {
    shell32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("shell32.dll")
    proc := shell32.NewProc("ILFree")
    proc.Call(pidlList)
}

func ILCreateFromPathW(pszPath string) (uintptr, error) {
    shell32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("shell32.dll")
    proc := shell32.NewProc("ILCreateFromPathW")

    pszPathPtr, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(pszPath)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    ret, _, err := proc.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pszPathPtr)))
    if ret == 0 {
        return 0, err
    }
    return ret, nil
}

func SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidlList uintptr, cild uint32, children uintptr) error {
    shell32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("shell32.dll")
    proc := shell32.NewProc("SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems")

    ret, _, err := proc.Call(pidlList, uintptr(cild), children, 0)
    if ret != 0 && err.Error() != "The operation completed successfully." {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

It doesn't work as nothing happened after I executed the code. The Explorer didn't appear.
I read some documents regarding the usage of the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenfolderandselectitems
Still not sure what's going on. Maybe it is not because of the programming language itself. I think calling DLL functions is a little bit complex in GO, and I probably did something wrong with the function calls.

In the Go code, why are you casting uint32 to uintptr in the 2nd parameter of SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems()? Just pass the uint32 as-is. It is expecting a 32bit integer, not a pointer-sized integer. Also, why are you checking the err.Error() message? If ret is not 0 then the function failed, and err.Error() should never be "The operation completed successfully." as that is the message text for error 0.

Because the signature is func (p *LazyProc) Call(a ...uintptr) and I must convert the parameters to uintptr. Also, the err.Error() is "The operation completed successfully." with ret equals to non-zero, I tested it

uintptr is the wrong type for the 2nd parameter. It must be a 32bit int whether you are running in 32bit or 64bit. Also, if ret is not 0 then the function failed, period. This function returns an error code directly, it doesn't use GetLastError() to report errors (neither does ILCreateFromPathW(), either), so you can't use err.Error() in this situation. If you need a human-readable message for the error code, you'll have to pass the error code to FormatMessageW() or equivalent

As explained in official SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems documentation remarks:

CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx must be called before using
SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems. Not doing so causes
SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems to fail.

So you must add something like this in your main for example:
func main() {
    ole32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("ole32.dll")
    proc := ole32.NewProc("CoInitialize")
    proc.Call(0)

    SelectInFileExplorer("C:\\Users")
}

It works in .NET because .NET does this automatically

Here is the complete solution:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)

var (
    shell32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("shell32.dll")
    user32  = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    ole32   = syscall.NewLazyDLL("ole32.dll")

    procCoInitializeEx             = ole32.NewProc("CoInitializeEx")
    procCoUninitialize             = ole32.NewProc("CoUninitialize")
    procILCreateFromPathW          = shell32.NewProc("ILCreateFromPathW")
    procSHOpenFolderAndSelectItems = shell32.NewProc("SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems")
    procILFree                     = shell32.NewProc("ILFree")
)

func UTF16String(s string) uintptr {
    ptr, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(s)
    if err != nil {
        return 0
    } else {
        return uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
    }
}

func main() {
    procCoInitializeEx.Call(0, 0) // nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED
    defer procCoUninitialize.Call()

    err := SelectInFileExplorer("C:\\Users")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }
}

func SelectInFileExplorer(fullPath string) error {
    // Alternative way to open explorer, but the explorer window will not be the front window
    // cmd := exec.Command("explorer", "/select,", path)
    // cmd.Run()

    if fullPath == "" {
        return fmt.Errorf("fullPath cannot be null or empty")
    }

    absPath, err := filepath.Abs(fullPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    pidlList, err := ILCreateFromPathW(absPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer ILFree(pidlList)

    if pidlList != 0 {
        err = SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidlList, 0, 0, 0)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func ILCreateFromPathW(pszPath string) (uintptr, error) {
    ret, _, err := procILCreateFromPathW.Call(UTF16String(pszPath))
    if ret == 0 {
        return 0, err
    }
    return ret, nil
}

func ILFree(pidlList uintptr) {
    procILFree.Call(pidlList)
}

func SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidlList uintptr, cild uint, children uintptr, dwFlags uint) error {
    ret, _, err := procSHOpenFolderAndSelectItems.Call(pidlList, uintptr(cild), children, uintptr(dwFlags))
    if ret != 0 {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}


Note in general, you shouldn't call CoInitialize(Ex) and CoUninitialize in "library code" or in a method. They should be called by the developer who creates the running thread (and implicitely who runs initial code in the first process thread). That's why I put CoInitialize in main, not near Shell API calls. Also you call CoInitializeEx which 1) is not needed here and 2) is incorrectly used with one parameter where it requires two.

yes, you are correct. I did notice that it requires two parameters when I was studying your answer. I just updated my answer and corrected the mistakes. Thank you for your help.
