# How to access tag information on office files via C#

Tags: c#, ms-office

I would like to write a simple bit of code that would extract only the tag information from a set of office (docx, pptx, etc.) files that exist in a directory so that it could be indexed and searched easily.

When I say "tag", I mean the tag info that you have been able to add to a file since Vista.  It's typically done using Explorer.  For example, the pptx file in the screenshot below has the tag, "bubble" attached.

[image: Example]

But searching those tags is already built into Windows, you say?  Why, yes, but I need this to only index the tags and I need to expose the info through an intranet rather than inside of Windows.

I have found that inside the office file package, the actual information is stored in /docProps/core.xml file in the cp:keywords element.  And I do realize that, in code, I could unzip the file, access that file, and extract what I need.  I'm hoping that there's a pre-abstracted solution out there somewhere, however.  I seriously doubt that's what Windows is doing to index that same information (but admittedly, I can't really find any good info on it).

I have also found some discussions about [IFilters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx).  And yet, this accesses the text of the file.  I don't see where an IFilter helps solve this particular problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have word installed but i'll guess that they are accessible from the standard property system as the KEYWORD entries as are the tags on a jpg picture.

If you want to know exactly how it's done, I played with the shell COM API and here is a full sample code in Gist : [FileTags.cs](https://gist.github.com/1285901). But that was just for fun you should use the [Microsoft Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) as their implementation is a lot cleaner.

To get the tags (called keywords internally) reference `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll` then :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(@"C:\path\to\some\file.jpg");
        var tags = (string[])shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.ValueAsObject;
        tags = tags ?? new string[0];
        Console.WriteLine("Tags: {0}", String.Join("; ", tags));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

if they didn't mess it up it should work starting from **Windows XP SP2** (*Mine should work from SP1 as I avoided the PropVariantGetStringElem but it's really annoying without them*).

Comment: Fun, eh?  VirtualBlackFox, you seem like a masochist of the highest degree.  Thanks for the direction.  The WindowsAPICodePack worked a treat.

Comment: No problem, i love understanding little details like that. Like my project to parse the binary data stored in the registry for the profile pictures ( https://github.com/vbfox/UserTile ) or my open explorer with files selected sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073353/c-how-to-open-windows-explorer-windows-with-a-number-of-files-selected/3578581#3578581

Comment: Is it possible to reverse engineer this? I've tried everything to programmaticly add tags to a file. I would really appreciate your help VBF.