# Enumerate files from a folder based on tags/keywords

Tags: c#, file, search-engine, keyword-search

In Windows, tags can be associated with files (docx, png, jpg, etc.).

How can I enumerate the files that are tagged with a specific keyword. C#.

I am looking for something like `Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*", "tag1")`

Comment: Have you looked at the COM interface? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759661/how-to-access-tag-information-on-office-files-via-c-sharp

Comment: @cDima This is perfect. Reply with an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the com interface for accessing tag information on files - [How to access tag information on office files via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759661/how-to-access-tag-information-on-office-files-via-c-sharp?lq=2)