# SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems dont select folders on win 10+

Tags: c#

I used class in this post
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073353/c-how-to-open-windows-explorer-windows-with-a-number-of-files-selected/3578581#3578581) for a long time.
But when i try it on win10/11, it doesnt work with network folders.

//Local folders selecting good, like

```
ShowSelectedInExplorer.FileOrFolders(@"C:\Windows\System32",@"C:\ProgramFiles");
```

//But when i try open network folder

```
ShowSelectedInExplorer.FileOrFolders(@"\\Parent network folder", new[] {"folder1","folder2"})
```

///It open parent folder, but not select child.

//Can u help me whats wrong?

Comment: Clean up the question. What's code, what's a comment and what's the question itself? The network path is invalid too - network folders start with \\