# Pass multiple files / folders from windows explorer to external application

Tags: c#, contextmenu, argument-passing, windows-explorer

Hi does anyone know how to get windows explorer to pass multiple files / folders through to an external app (c#) referenced in the registry?

I am current able to act upon a single file / folder using the %1 syntax but not sure how to get explorer to pass through multiple items.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you considered drag and drop?

Comment: Hi, yes ive considered this but would prefer to use the context menu in explorer.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer

Comment: SendTo in c#. would you like me to google that for you? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select multiple files in Explorer, your shell context menu extension's IShellExtInit::Initialize method will be called and pdtobj contains the selection.
Note writing managed shell extension is not supported.

Comment: Supported, smuportted. We don need no steenkin sport! ;-)

Comment: +1 for noting that writing a managed shell extension isn't supported.

Comment: The latest .Net 4.0 runtime supports in process side-by-side loading of the .Net 4.0 runtime (and ALL future runtimes) with earlier .Net runtimes.

See following excerpt from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx 
"With the ability to have multiple runtimes in process with any other runtime, we can now offer general support for writing managed shell extensions—even those that run in-process with arbitrary applications on the machine."

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible.

When you open multiple files using Explorer, it will launch a separate copy of your program for file.  I don't think it's possible to override this behavior.

**EDIT**: I forgot about shell extensions.  This is possible.

To work around this, you could make the subsequent copies communicate with the first one, then exit.  Detailed instructions for this are beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this reliably you would need to write a shell extension, most likely a sendto implementation.

I haven't written one since vb6 but you can find what looks to be a good managed example **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide6.aspx)**

Or you could use a [**freeware utility**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)