# Pass multiple parameters with open command

Tags: windows, shell, vim, registry, explorer

I am looking for ways to open multiple documents in a single application instance. For example, open multiple documents in a single, new gVim instance.

I had found this code on here before, but it doesn't quite do what I want.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Open with &Vim]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Open with &Vim\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\avt\\Programs\\PortableApps\\gVimPortable\\gVimPortable.exe\" -p --remote-tab-silent \"%1\" \"%*\""
```

The problem is that it is giving a similar effect, but not the one I want (it opens the selected documents in an existing gVim instance, not all of them in their OWN new gVim instance). What I want is like this:

1. Highlight 5 documents in Explorer
2. Open them
3. A single gVim instance opens with all 5 documents as tabs

I think this would work, if only I could pass multiple arguments!

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Open with &Vim]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Open with &Vim\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\avt\\Programs\\PortableApps\\gVimPortable\\gVimPortable.exe\" -p \"%allselecteddocuments\""
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I just found out I can do this by adding a custom SendTo command (create a shortcut in your SendTo folder to gVim add -p to the Target. Is there any way to do this outside of the SendTo menu?

Comment: `vim -p` is what you need & you already know that. So your questions narrows down to "how to pass multiple selected items as single command line, via registry."

Comment: Check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826791/how-to-pass-in-multiple-file-folder-paths-via-a-rigth-click-eventverb-to-an-ex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623370/how-do-you-call-multiple-files-from-command-line-into-your-applicaiton

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut in `C:\Users\\\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` folder with ONLY the exe name.

Now you should be able to select random multiple files and use context `SendTo\<shortcut>`  to open them with your designated exe.