# Showing file in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, explorer

My favorite IDE [Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/) has a command for showing the active file in Explorer. This means that when you launch the command, it opens an explorer window on the folder that the file is in, and then selects the file.

The problem is, that if the window is already open, it fails to select the file. It activates the window, but the file doesn't get selected. That's annoying. I want the file to always be selected

I spoke to one of the developers and he said that they're using `'explorer /select,%s' % filename` to show the file, and that the above annoyance might be a quirk of that command.

Does anyone have an idea how to avoid this behavior?

(The solution needs to work in Windows 2000, XP, 2003 Server, Vista, and Windows 7.)

Comment: A related question exists, one of the answers points to API calls; It might help a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887364/opening-an-explorer-window-with-designated-file-selected

Comment: On which OS do you see the problem? Do you see the same problem when running 'explorer /select,...' from a cmd.exe?

Comment: 1. It happens on XP. 2. I tested, and yes, the same problem happens when I run it directly from a terminal.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you modify the Wing IDE shortcut so that it runs in compatibility mode (e.g. XP SP3 mode)?

Comment: I am already running on Windows XP. The compatibility options are 95, 98&Me, NT4SP5, and 2000.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457, which states "switches can be combined", what about:

```
explorer /n,/select,c:\path\to\file.ext
```

/n *should* force a new window.

Comment: I don't want to force a new window. I want to use an existing one if it exists.

Comment: Ah, I see. I can't see a programmatic solution to your problem in that case, since there are no command line switches to achieve what you want, and if shell coding isn't an option, that's about it. There might be configuration tweaks you could do on each machine, but that'd be a question for superuser.com not stackoverflow since this is a programming Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if one exists, but if you create utility which would be implement such solution(C++) it would work as you expected:

```
void OpenFileInExplorer(LPCTSTR filename)
{
    ITEMIDLIST *pidl = ILCreateFromPath(filename);
    if(pidl) 
    {
        SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl,0,0,0);
        ILFree(pidl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I can't program in C++ so this doesn't help me.

Comment: I do not see C++ in the given code. BTW, don't forget to call `CoInitializeEx` before calling SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems!

Comment: @Werner Henze: that's right, call `CoInitializeEx` first is obligatory and... that code was actually writen in C++, :-) I know only C++, C# and ABAP. And the code above can be recognized only like C++ for me