# python open windows explorer

Tags: python, windows, explorer

Please image such a situation: A local file's icon is displayed in a GUI, right click the icon, a context menu pops, with the option: show file in explorer. Click the option, then a explorer window opened, with the particular file selected. Many editors have such a feature: show in folder or show in explorer

In fact, the GUI is built by PyQt,  my first thought is simple, just open a subprocess and pass the command line:

`explorer /select, a_full_path_name`

The behavior is indeed what I need, but when click "show in folder" again, a new explorer window will be opened, even the old one exsits! How about a naughty boy clicking "show in folder" dozens of times in a breath? So I need just one window, if an old one exists, just raise it to the front.

The command `start /D a_path .` may disappoint the naughty boy(run it several times, only one window.) however, there is no option to highlight a selected file, thus also disappoint me...

As mentioned above, many editors have such a "show in folder" feature, 
but to my suprise, **PyCharm** "Show in Explorer" will open multiple windows with multiple clicks on the same file, and also the **CodeBlocks** "opening containing folder", however **programmer's notepad** "open containing folder" will always open just one folder on the same file.(To be honest, I have only the 3 editors in my PC except the windows notepad :)

---

**My Question:**
Can the feature mentioned above be achieved just by windows cmd?
If can not, Is there a python way to achieve that?

In fact, I found several related questions in stackoverflow, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702222/showing-file-in-windows-explorer),
but my problem is unsolved, would somebody give me a ride?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, some nice guy guided me to the answer.
It's from https://github.com/exaile/exaile/blob/master/xl/common.py#L350

**in py3+**

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.ole32.CoInitialize(None)
upath = r"C:\Windows"
pidl = ctypes.windll.shell32.ILCreateFromPathW(upath)
ctypes.windll.shell32.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 0, None, 0)
ctypes.windll.shell32.ILFree(pidl)
ctypes.windll.ole32.CoUninitialize()
```

**in py2+**

Just give a unicode path.
note: `ILCreateFromPathW` (Unicode) and `ILCreateFromPathA` (ANSI)