# VB.NET, open specific folder in windows explorer?

Tags: vb.net

I have problem with opening specific folder in VB.net in Windows Explorer.  I used

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", "Folder_Path")`

Always when i tried this it open documents in explorer , whatever i wrote. Pls help.

Comment: Check this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887364/opening-an-explorer-window-with-designated-file-selected>

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
Process.Start("directory path")
```

Comment: This fails on Windows 10 with "Access denied" exception, even if I wrap the path in double quotes.  However, specifying "explorer.exe" and passing the path as an argument--like all the other answers--works.  Despite the error, it is not about folder access rights.

Answer (score 9):

Try opening it with:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/root,Folder_Path")
```

Or change the path before:

```
SetCurrentDirectory("Folder_Path")
Process.Start("explorer.exe")
```

And if it still fails, go with the shell command:

```
Shell("explorer Folder_Path", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

Comment: it again open just documents

Answer (score 9):

You could start explorer with preselected directory like this:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", String.Format("/n, /e, {0}", "d:\yourdirectory\"))
```

The Windows Explorer options are explained in this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457/en-us).

Comment: @Chad Gilbert: The question relates to VB.NET and not C#. All strings in VB.NET are verbatim strings. The @ character in VB.NET produces an error!

Comment: Why bother linking KB articles since MicroShit keeps re-arranging and the link gets lost. The title was "Windows Explorer Command-Line Options"

Comment: @sproketboy internet links can change and go broken over time. At the time as the answer was given, 2 years ago, the link was working and IMO it was a helpful addition. Yes,, it would have been nice to redirect the KB article from msdn to the new https://learn.microsoft.com/ page.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why it opens the default directory (MyDocuments) only could be one of these two reasons:

- The directory does not exist.
- The directory path contains spaces in the name, and arguments containing spaces should be enclosed with doublequotes, this is a BASIC rule of programming.

**Then use the syntax properly:**

```
    Dim Proc As String = "Explorer.exe"

    Dim Args As String =
       ControlChars.Quote &
       IO.Path.Combine("C:\", "Folder with spaces in the name") &
       ControlChars.Quote

    Process.Start(Proc, Args)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," + "C:\File_Name.txt")
```

The `.txt` could be what ever u need.

Comment: This only works if `C:\File_Name.txt` exists. Otherwise explorer.exe opens on the root directory, especially, if the filename would be `C:\temp\subdir\File_Name.txt`. It does not open in `C:\temp\subdir`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "Folder_Path")` like you said.

The only reason that Windows Explorer opens the Documents folder is that you mistyped the "folder_path" and the specified folder does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but there is no reason to get overly complicated; so, just use like this:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", Chr(34) & "folder to open" & Chr(34))
```