# Highlight(select) file in windows explorer using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a list of file names. These files are inside a single folder. Is it possible using .Net to select/highlight the files in windows explorer?

I would like to simulate the selection as shown in the explorer screenshot below.

Note: I know how to search/copy/move files in .Net. But this is something which I have not read anywhere in my google search attempts.

I went through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9355/1246550), but it is dealing with shell functions. I am looking for anything that can be done through c#.

[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: There's a lot of unknowns here

Comment: @marsze -I looked at it before posting..i was wondering if it is possible with c#

Comment: @vinayan There is also an C# example under the link I posted. However, this *does* use shell-functions, but you won't get around that. Why don't you want that?