# How to select multiple files in Windows Explorer from selected cells in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have several folders containing over 1000 subfolders each. I have to move some of them (about half) to other locations depending on the progress made within eachsubfolder. The progress is notated in a spreadsheet, which also provides its path. I have the following code:

```
    Sub open_explorer()
    Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select, K:\user\folder\A\" & ActiveCell.Value, vbMaximizedFocus
    End Sub
```

So, this code will open a window explorer with a file selected (such file is the one that follows the path + ActiveCell value. 
Is there a way to select multiple files at once? Lets say I want to select 200 cells, so Window Explorer will open with the 200 files selected?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer - (the answers are somewhat old though, and not about vba)

Comment: It is slightly complicated. Let me post an answer and explain it

Comment: Thanks @KekuSemau, I saw that post, but wasn't applicable.

Comment: The obvious question to me is what will be done with them once you have them selected.  Why not move them instead?

Comment: + 1 A very good question! I have posted a solution. You may have to refresh the page to see it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately `/select` option will only let you select single file. There is no other option which will let you select multiple files. You may confirm that by checking this MS [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q314853)

Having said that, is it possible to achieve that in VBA since the API `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` is not available? The answer is

> **YES**

Follow these steps.

1. Open a module and add a reference to `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation` and  `Microsoft Internet Controls` as shown below

   [image]
2. Next for testing purpose, we will take the folder `C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Test1` which has 5 csv files numbered from 1 to 5 as shown below.

   [image]
3. Now paste the below code in a module and run the procedure `Sub Sample()`

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    SelectMultipleFiles "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Test1"
End Sub

Sub SelectMultipleFiles(sFolder As String)
    Dim wb As WebBrowser
    Dim objExp As Shell32.Shell
    
    Set objExp = New Shell32.Shell
    
    objExp.Open sFolder
    
    '~~> Find our explorer window
    Do While wb Is Nothing: Set wb = GetExplorer(sFolder): Loop
    
    '~~> We are going to select files 1,3 and 5.csv
    '~~> The 5& is used so that any previous selections are cleared off
    Call wb.document.SelectItem(sFolder & "\1.csv", 5&)
    Call wb.document.SelectItem(sFolder & "\3.csv", 1&)
    Call wb.document.SelectItem(sFolder & "\5.csv", 1&)
End Sub

'~~> Function to find the releavnt explorer window
Function GetExplorer(sFolder As String) As WebBrowser
    Dim objExp As New Shell32.Shell
    Dim wb1 As WebBrowser

    For Each wb1 In objExp.Windows
        If wb1.Name = "Windows Explorer" And _
        LCase(wb1.document.Folder.Self.Path) = LCase(sFolder) Then
            Set GetExplorer = wb1
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**Output:**

[image]

**NOTE**: As mentioned by @ChrisB, in Windows 10, the `WebBrowser.Name` property returns `File Explorer` instead of `Windows Explorer` so to make it compatible for both versions you can use

```
If wb1.Name = "Windows Explorer" or wb1.Name = "File Explorer"....
```

Alternatively you can use `WMI` to find the Windows version and then choose between **Windows/File Explorer**

Comment: Really interesting! `.Name` is `Windows-Explorer` in my case, however (Win7). Is that a typo or does it vary?

Comment: The above is tested on Win 7 :)

Comment: @KekuSemau I posted a variation of the last function

Comment: In Windows 10, the WebBrowser.Name property returns `File Explorer`.  Replace this:  `If wb1.Name = "Windows Explorer"` with `If wb1.Name = "File Explorer"`.

Answer (score 3):

[Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout)'s answer is quite useful. Nevertheless, it works only in Windows platforms where the title of the window is `"Windows Explorer"`.

To get this to work on Windows 8/8.1/10 (and not only Windows 7 in English), we could use this function definition of `GetExplorer`:

```
'~~> Function to find the relevant explorer window
Function GetExplorer(sFolder As String) As WebBrowser
    Dim objExp As New Shell32.Shell
    Dim wb1 As WebBrowser

    For Each wb1 In objExp.Windows
        If UCase(wb1.FullName) = "C:\WINDOWS\EXPLORER.EXE" Then
            If LCase(wb1.Document.Folder.Self.Path) = LCase(sFolder) Then
                Set GetExplorer = wb1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```