# How launch batch photos/images in gallery view in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, photos

For a project I have folders of images.  An example folder might be ImagesOfDogs, and the images inside would be sequentially named (1.png, 2.png, etc.).  I have a button, and when I press this button I want to open all of the images in a folder at once, in one window.  I could make my own window, but I would rather use the default Windows program so the user can edit the photos.  *This would look like the following (just imagine that black thing is a really cute dog pic):*
[image]

Let's say the path to a folder is a string titled sPathToFolderOfDogs.  On my button click, I want a method like this:

```
private void OpenCoolPicsOfDogs()
{
    Process.Start(sPathToFolderOfDogs);
}
```

Except that will open all enclosed files in an image viewing application, preferably whichever is the user default.  I have tried:

```
Process.Start("PictureViewer", sPathToFolderOfDogs);
```

...which opens PictureViewer and does not open my photos in PictureViewer,

```
Process.Start(sPathToParticularImage1);
Process.Start(sPathToParticularImage2);
etc etc
```

...which opens each in a new window,
and possibly most creatively/desperately:

```
String[] arrayOfAllMyPathsToParticularImagesInTheFolder;
(put all the strings in the array)
Process.Start(arrayOfAllMyPathsToParticularImagesInTheFolder);
```

Which just crashed.  I know opening folders in applications through Process.Start should be possible because it is done in the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx).*  Is there a way to do it with images?

*relevant code from link:

> ```
>        // Start Internet Explorer. Defaults to the home page.
>
>         Process.Start("IExplore.exe");
>
>         // Display the contents of the favorites folder in the browser.
>
>         Process.Start(myFavoritesPath);
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically select multiple files in windows explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my question was a duplicate.  However, I am not deleting it, as [the powers that be suggest it is best to keep duplicates up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate) as a "signpost" informing future searchers where the true path lies.

[Here is the answer to my question (or more specifically, about half a dozen equally functional answers to my question).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer)

TL;DR: The solution I am now using is from @bruceatk in the above link.