# How I can Highlight the list of files in a certain directory?

Tags: c#, windows, file, com, directory

I would like to know how I can show the list of files in a certain directory as highlighted or selected. I followed this article [Programmatically select multiple files in windows explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programmatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer)

Here's what I tried, But still i am unable to see the files as highlighted:

ViewModel.cs

```
List<string> ListOfFiles = new List<string>();

 private void ShowFolderAndSeeHighlightedFiles()
 {
    //Open the folder path through NativeMethods class
    NativeMethods.OpenFolderAndSelectFiles(sLogFolderPath, ListOfFiles.ToArray());

 }
```

NativeMethods.cs

```
public static class NativeMethods
    {

        [DllImport("shell32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(
            IntPtr pidlFolder,
            uint cidl,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] IntPtr[] apidl,
            uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr ILCreateFromPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string pszPath);

        [ComImport]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        [Guid("000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        public interface IShellLinkW
        {
            [PreserveSig]
            int GetPath(StringBuilder pszFile, int cch, [In, Out] ref WIN32_FIND_DATAW pfd, uint fFlags);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetIDList([Out] out IntPtr ppidl);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetIDList([In] ref IntPtr pidl);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetDescription(StringBuilder pszName, int cch);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetDescription([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetWorkingDirectory(StringBuilder pszDir, int cch);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetWorkingDirectory([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDir);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetArguments(StringBuilder pszArgs, int cch);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetArguments([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszArgs);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetHotkey([Out] out ushort pwHotkey);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetHotkey(ushort wHotkey);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetShowCmd([Out] out int piShowCmd);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetShowCmd(int iShowCmd);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetIconLocation(StringBuilder pszIconPath, int cch, [Out] out int piIcon);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetIconLocation([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszIconPath, int iIcon);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetRelativePath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPathRel, uint dwReserved);

            [PreserveSig]
            int Resolve(IntPtr hwnd, uint fFlags);

            [PreserveSig]
            int SetPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFile);
        }

        [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode), BestFitMapping(false)]
        public struct WIN32_FIND_DATAW
        {
            public uint dwFileAttributes;
            public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
            public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
            public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
            public uint nFileSizeHigh;
            public uint nFileSizeLow;
            public uint dwReserved0;
            public uint dwReserved1;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            public string cFileName;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
            public string cAlternateFileName;
        }


        public static void OpenFolderAndSelectFiles(string folder, params string[] filesToSelect)
        {           
            IntPtr dir = ILCreateFromPath(folder);

            var filesToSelectIntPtrs = new IntPtr[filesToSelect.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < filesToSelect.Length; i++)
            {
                filesToSelectIntPtrs[i] = ILCreateFromPath(filesToSelect[i]);
            }

            SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(dir, (uint)filesToSelect.Length, filesToSelectIntPtrs, 0);

            ReleaseComObject(dir);

            ReleaseComObject(filesToSelectIntPtrs);
        }


        private static void ReleaseComObject(params object[] comObjs)
        {            
            foreach (object obj in comObjs)
            {
                if (obj != null && Marshal.IsComObject(obj))
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works fine for me but. Make sure when you add files, you use the full file path, including the parent directory.

Comment: You should have seen that, if the path is relative or contains file names only, the returned `IntPtr` for the `ITEMIDLIST` is 0.

Comment: Also, you have memory leaks on IntPtr, you must call Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem on all allocated PIDLs (IntPtr), not call Marshal.ReleaseComObject. PIDLs are not COM objects

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @Simon Mourier. I followed your suggestion to send the full file paths and replace Marshal.ReleaseComObject with Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem. Problem got solved apparently.